# Forms is having previously filled data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form having many inputs,  as vue file size increased, I decided to place binding data in the script to another js file and import it as follows

even I am doing a shallow copy, after submitting the form and going to same
form it containing the same data that filled before it needs to be empty

```
----  form.vue------
  import Camp from '~/models/camp/camp'
   data: () => ({
     .....
     camp: {...Camp},
     .....

    })
----------models/camp/camp.js
module.exports= {
     name="",
     etc..
}
------------
```

Comment: Just make the form empty after the submit using reset()

Comment: Are all attributes of `camp` kept from one form to the other or only parts of it? Is the `name` attribute one of those?

Comment: yes all attributes of camp kept in another camp.js file which contains name attribute also

Comment: That's not quite what I meant to ask. Please show more attributes from the Camp object. Also if you fill out the name in the form, submit and go back to it, is the old name kept? Is it the same for all the attributes of Camp or only some? Also, be sure to tag the person you're replying to with (e.g. `@bernie`) so they get a message alert.

Comment: Either `reset` on submit or use a deep copy instead of shallow.